# Need to access detailTextLabel property of UITableViewCell when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have programmatically created a UITableView and I have also programmatically created UIButtons to be included with every cell / row. I have set these buttons so that if they are tapped, their button image changes. So when the user first sees the table view, the buttons are the color grey, but if the user taps one of the buttons, then that button will turn red. If they tap it again, it will turn back to grey.

I need to make it so that if a button has been pressed, and is currently using the red image, then it will pass it's cell's detailTextLabel property value into an NSMutableArray object.

Here is my code that controls the majority of the UITableView. This is where the cell's textLabels and detalTextLabels are set:

```
userName = [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *firstNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *userNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsUsernameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *addUserButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];

UIImage *addUserButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];

UIButton *addUserButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

addUserButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView];

[cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView];

[cell.contentView addSubview:addUserButton];
```

The most important parts of the above code are these statements:

```
[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

The above control the settings for the different states of the button, and this helps make the button turn to the grey image or the red image when it is pressed.

The below statement is a method call that handles the "touch" events and makes the button change from the grey image to the red image when it is pressed:

```
[addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And here is the above method's method implementation in my View Controller:

```
- (void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    NSLog(@"Has sender state changed?: %u", sender.state);   
}
```

You will notice that I am using NSLog to print out the button's state. The "state" property changes it's value every time one of the button's is pressed. Now I need to figure out a way to make it so that if a specific button's state is changed, we will grab it's cell's "detailTextLabel" property and place it inside an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the addUserButton.tag property to keep tableview index row (1), so inside the handleTouchUpInside (2) you can find button row:

1- Set indexPath row inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
//Keep indexPath.row on Button.tag
addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

2- Find button on TableView Rows

```
- (void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellButton.tag inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"teste";

}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: I added your code and it does not change anything at all.

Comment: Did you set the tag property on addUserButton creation, before add it to cell subview?

Comment: Are you asking me, if in my original code I posted, if I added a tag property to my UIButton object called "addUserButton" ?

Comment: Take a look on the answer now, i complemented it with the tag property

Comment: Carentes, I implemented your code and I think it is going to work, but I can only get it to print the first row aka index 0. Here's the problem: I added your "addUserButton.tag" code and right after it I added an NSLog. For some reason, it always prints to the console as 0.

Comment: Any idea why when it NSLogs it is always showing 0, even though the table clearly has multiple rows and cells?

Comment: Your original code are inside viewDidLoad or on tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: something is wrong with your code of "[tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row". For example, I can do "_addUserButton.tag = _tableView.rowHeight;" and it then the tag will NSLog as "44". I can even set it to a number like 9 and it will NSLog as "9".

Comment: I need to know more about your code, my sample just gonna work if you use this inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, how you are doing to add the cell to tableview? show me the code.

Comment: All of the code that I included in my qustion is located inside the method implementation for cellForRowAtIndexPath ie. "-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath"

Comment: So you just need to use:  addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row

Comment: I changed it to the row property of indexPath and it is working perfectly now. Thanks carantes!

Comment: is there any we can talk in chat for 2 minutes? Your code works perfectly but for some reason the very first button trigger's my 2nd section's first button every time. All of the buttons work perfectly, except the very first one. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the essence of how you'd subclass UITableViewCell to accomplish this (condensed a bit to save space...)  First the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SampleCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@end


@protocol FancyProtocolNameGoesHere
- (void)doSomethingWithThisText:(NSString*)text fromThisCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell;  
@end
```

And the .m

```
#import "SampleCell.h"

@interface SampleCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;
- (void)handleTouchUpInside;

@end


@implementation SampleCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self configureCell];
    }
    return self;
} 

- (void)configureCell
{
    _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    //Configure all the images etc, for the button
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_button]; //you'd probably want to set the frame first...
}

- (void)handleTouchUpInside
{
    if (_button.selected) {
        [self.delegate doSomethingWithThisText:self.textLabel.text fromThisCell:self];
    }
    _button.selected = !_button.selected;
}

@end
```

Register this subclass with the TableView (remember to declare conformity to the protocol), and assign the delegate to self within `-(UITableViewCell*)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

The final magic comes as you implement `- (void)doSomethingWithThisText:(NSString*)text fromThisCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell;`  because you can call `[self indexPathForCell:cell]` on the cell parameter you passed in to get the index path you probably need so you know where to insert the text in your NSMutableArray data object.

A subclassed UITableViewCell with a delegate protocol pattern is not the only way to do this, but I think it makes some sense for what you described.

Answer (score 0):

This solutions is safe to table sections.

```
- (void)onButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender event:(id)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    /* use cell here */
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused. What do you mean by "Safe to table sections" ?

Comment: If you will use button's tag value, you can assign only `row`. How you can detect which `section` and `row` pressed, if know only row? I my solution, you no can know `row` and `section` (full index path) for detect cell.