# UIButton on UITableViewCell is being linked to the wrong action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have programmatically created a UITableView and I have also programmatically created UIButtons to be included with every cell / row. I have set these buttons so that if they are tapped, their button image changes. So when the user first sees the table view, the buttons are the color grey, but if the user taps one of the buttons, then that button will turn red. If they tap it again, it will turn back to grey.

I have also made it so that if a button has been pressed, and is currently using the red image, then it will pass it's cell's detailTextLabel property value into an NSMutableArray object.

Here's the problem though. For some reason, all of the buttons work fine except for the very first one. My UITableView has 2 sections. If I press the button for the first cell in the first section, for some reason it is grabbing the detailTextLabel property of the 2nd section's first cell.

Here is my code that controls the majority of the UITableView. This is where the cell's textLabels and detalTextLabels are set. The reason it is an if statement, is because if we find the person in our database then we perform the first code, else they weren't found in our database and we perform the second set of code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

_cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

NSString* userName = nil;

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

userName = [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *firstNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *userNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsUsernameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


UIImage *addUserButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];
UIImage *addUserButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];


_addUserButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);

[_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[_addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


_addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;


[_cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView];

[_cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView];

[_cell.contentView addSubview:_addUserButton];


} else {

userName = [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *firstNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *userNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


UIImage *addFriendButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];
UIImage *addFriendButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];

UIButton *addFriendButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

addFriendButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);


[addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];     

[addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[addFriendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row;


[_cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView];

[_cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView];

[_cell.contentView addSubview:addFriendButton];

}
return _cell;
}
```

The below statements are  method calls, one for the first part of the if statement, and another for the "else" part of the if statement. They handle the "touch" events and make the buttons change from the grey image to the red image when they are pressed:

```
[_addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
[addFriendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here are the method implementations for these method calls. They are nearly identical except for the names of "handleTouchUpInside" and "handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers", and then the first one's section is set to "0", and the second one's section is set to "1".

```
- (void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
sender.selected = !sender.selected;

UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton *)sender;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellButton.tag inSection:0];

_cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

_cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_cell.detailTextLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@""];

if(sender.state == 5) {

[_usersToAddToFriendsList addObject:_cell.detailTextLabel.text];

} else {

[_usersToAddToFriendsList removeObject:_cell.detailTextLabel.text];


}
}


- (void)handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:(UIButton *)sender {
sender.selected = !sender.selected;

UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton *)sender;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellButton.tag inSection:1];


_cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(sender.state == 5) {

[_usersToInviteToApp addObject:_cell.detailTextLabel.text];


} else {

[_usersToInviteToApp removeObject:_cell.detailTextLabel.text];

}   
}
```

Another important part of the first code that I showed you, is how I am setting the UIButton tag's in both parts of the if statement. I have a feeling these may be part of the problem:

`addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;` and  `addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row;`

These are used to add a tag to each button. I added these in because I asked a question on SO yesterday when I was first trying to set all of this up, and the button tags were part of the solution someone gave me. Here is the solution/answer I ended up using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22030199/3344977

Last but not least, here are the final 3 method implementations that help create my UITableView and all of it's aspects:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2 ;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section == 0)
    return [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray count];
if(section == 1)
    return [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray count];

else return 0;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section == 0)
    return @"Friends Using This App";
if(section == 1)
    return @"Send to Contact";

else return @"nil";
}
```

UPDATE: I added an NSLog for the cell button's tag to the method implementations for "handleTouchUpInside" and "handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers". All of the buttons print the correct button tag to the console. So for the first button in the first section, it does print the correct button tag number of "0". So I think the real problem is that for some reason, the very first button in the first section, is being assigned to the wrong section.

I think it is being assigned to the 2nd section instead of the first.

UPDATE 2: Right now, when you press one of the buttons, it is supposed to access the property "detailTextLabel.text". All of the buttons do this fine except the first one in the first section.

For this first button however, even if I change the property to "textLabel.text", it still ALWAYS prints the "detailTextLabel.text" of the 2nd section's first cell.

UPDATE 3: For the first part of the if statement, which creates the first section of the table view, instead of using both "SliderThumb-Normal" and "SliderThumb-Normal-G" for the images I changed them both to just "SliderThumb-Normal". Sure enough, the 2nd cell in the first section is correct and is using the image of "SliderThumb-Normal", but the first cell in the first section is using the image of "SliderThumb-Normal-G".

I think when the if statement is running, the first cell must not have a section of "0", because it is being run through the "else" part of the if code. I just can't figure out why.

EDIT FOR TIMOTHY: I put a lot of them inside the interface area of my main file and also my header file.

Here is my header file:

```
@interface AddFriendsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friendsOnApp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *objects;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *objectsFinal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *addFriendsTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PotentialFriend *potentialFriend;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PotentialFriend *potentialFriendForTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *potentialFriendz;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFile;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewCell *cell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewCell *cellz;


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *addUserButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *addFriendButton;


@end
```

Here is my main file's interface area:

```
@interface AddFriendsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* contactList;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *potentiaFriendsUsernameArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *removalPhoneNumberArray;


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *usersToAddToFriendsList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *usersToInviteToApp;

@end
```

And then I initialize these in the viewDidLoad method implementation of the main file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//This sets the UITableView's data source as itself.

self.tableView.dataSource = self;

self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.potentiaFriendsUsernameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.removalPhoneNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


self.usersToAddToFriendsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.usersToInviteToApp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.addUserButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
self.addFriendButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];


self.cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
```

Comment: Can you please post a non-truncated version of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: Just updated it for you Aaron.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your issue, but as you scroll through the tableview, the cells are reused, and you'll be adding more and more `_addUserButton`s and `addFriendButton`s.  Also, it looks like you're making a bunch of buttons and trying to store them all in the same property/instance variable.  Your table view will slow down substantially if the user scrolls for a while.  You should detect if the view has already been created and reconfigure it.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I really appreciate the help. Could you please provide some code so I can "detect if the view has already been created and reconfigure it" as you said?

Comment: Search for "UITableViewCell viewWithTag" - there are plenty of
 examples on here.

Comment: I have been trying various methods using that search and I am still getting the same results. Nevermind possible performance issues in the future, the facts are that every single button works except for the first cell in the first section. Even the second cell in the first section works. There has to be a reason why the very first cell being created is not working properly.

Comment: There are so many issues with this code it is hard to find a starting point. I would suggest that you study some table view examples and start over. @AaronBrager He's using tags to capture the row # (apparently for data model lookups through target action events). So he can't use tags in the cell config logic.

Comment: @TimothyMoose , this was my first attempt at a table view and I created it by looking at examples in the first place. What exactly are some of the main issues with my code that you're talking about? Can you at least point out some of the issues you see?

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense if you could show where `_addUserButton` gets set.

Comment: @TimothyMoose, I just added an edit/update for you at the very bottom. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Some things that are wrong: (1) you're treating cells as if they're always new.  Sometimes after you dequeue them, they're used.  (2) you're using instance variables (which let you point to *one* of something) to store references to objects on your cell (of which there are *multiple*). These items could be properties on a UITableViewCell subclass, but it doesn't make sense on a UIViewController subclass.

Comment: Honestly, I recommend you stop working on your project, take a few hours to read all of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html and http://www.mobilesce.com/2011/12/27/the-best-way-to-do-custom-reusable-uitableviewcells/ - this will all make more sense to you after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample project to turn the button background in each cell to grey and back to white when tapped. Take a look at my code so you can amend your code accordingly.

I have created two classes. The first is a UITableViewController and the second is a UITableViewCell.

I suggest that you run it standalone if you get confused and cannot get it integrated into your project. You can then copy and paste the code piece by piece until you get it to the point you want. Good luck!

**TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@property NSArray *tableDataArray;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableDataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First line", @"Second line", @"Third line", @"Fourth line", @"Fifth line", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.tableDataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
cell.IndexPath = indexPath;

return cell;
}

@end
```

**CustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *theButton;

-(void)didTapButtonInCell;

@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize indexPath, theButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    theButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [theButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 30)];
    [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButtonInCell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.accessoryView = theButton;
    }
return self;
}

-(void)setIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath {
indexPath = theIndexPath;
UILabel *theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 200, 25)];
[theLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
[theLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", self.indexPath.row]];
[self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.contentView addSubview:theLabel];
theButton = (UIButton *)self.accessoryView;
[theButton setTitle:@"Hit me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
theButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

-(void)didTapButtonInCell {
NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button at section %d row %d was tapped.", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button tapped!"
                                                message:messageString
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];

if([theButton.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]])
{
    [theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
} else
    {
    [theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I am hard at work playing with your code. One problem though. I am accessing address book data in TableViewController.m, but I just realized that in order to set the Row text you have to customize this statement "[theLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", self.indexPath.row]];" in CustomCell.m. How can I pass the data from TableViewController.m to CustomCell.m?

Comment: Create a NSString property in the CustomCell class and pass a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you guys are curious, the thing that was causing the problem was using the global variable `_addUserButton`

I ended up deleting the property for it, and just initializing it inside of the method implementation for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Can someone please explain to me why using it as a global variable was causing this problem?

Comment: Your are creating one UIButton in your ViewController. I think you need to create this button in your custom UITableViewCell because if I understood right, your cells will have one button each one.

Answer (score 0):

Any elements added dynamically to a cell must be identified by unique tag and if no element exists then only it should be created. here button is created each time but it should not be created.

button's tag should be constant not variable like indexpath.row.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableview:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   if([cell.contentView viewWithTag:10])
   {
      UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
      btn.tag=10;
      [cell.contentView addSubView:btn];
   }
   UIButton *button=[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10])
   //do button customizations
}
```

Now to uniquely identify button's cell and indexpaths in touch event

```
- (void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)sender.superview.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    //do action based on indexpath
}
```